# How to set maven proxy

Tags: maven, proxy

I tried to set maven proxy in NetBeans 7.4 since I am behind a proxy. I setup the proxy in NetBeans from Tools>Options>General>Proxy Settings, and it's working fine. But I still getting error when I was trying to build my project.

```
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 1]
```

I googled the error message, and then setup the the same proxy in settings.xml file of maven, but error occurs again.

```
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Not authorized by proxy , ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authentication Required. -> [Help 1]
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Add proxy settings:

```
<proxies>
    <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
     |-->
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxyhost</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>localhost|*.google.com.*</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
       </proxies>
```

Comment: Please post your maven local repository settings.xml

Comment: Proxy settings added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is probably an NTLM proxy? If it is:

Download the wagon-http-lightweight-2.2.jar from 
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http-lightweight/2.2/wagon-http-lightweight-2.2.jar

Copy the wagon-http-lightweight-2.2.jar to %M2_HOME%/lib/ext folder.

Answer (score 1):

As you said. You're using NetBean as IDE. please check the maven used in IDE. Maybe you are using the **embedded maven plugin**. then it will not work even you change the settings.xml under

> /Users/username/.m2/settings.xml

Comment: after wasting 3 hours i recollected that i have pointed my maven from my eclipse IDE, so from now onwards i am able to run build from eclipse IDE but from command prompt it is giving me error mentioned below Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer

Answer (score 1):

Set the proxy in the settings.xml file in the $MAVEN_HOME/conf folder or whetever you are storing the settings.xml file.

In the settings.xml, add this section (it can be added anywhere inside `<settings>` and `</settings>`:

```
<proxies>
 <proxy>
    <id>example-proxy</id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <host>172.20.201.42</host>   <!-- add your proxy host IP here -->
    <port>8080</port> <!-- add your proxy host port here -->
    <nonProxyHosts>  <!-- non proxy hosts separated by | (pipe) character -->
      172.*|10.*
    </nonProxyHosts>
  </proxy>
</proxies>
```

You can find the maven documentation on proxies here:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html