# Maven 3.2.3 ignores proxy settings

Tags: google-app-engine, proxy, maven-3

I am trying to upload my google app engine project using Maven (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/uploading).

Since Google App Engine is not accessible from Iran I am trying to use a proxy to connect, the proxy works fine when I am deploying python projects.

I set the Maven global settings.xml as follow:

`<proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>https</protocol>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>proxypass</password>
      <host>127.0.0.1</host>
      <port>8580</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>`

I copy settings.xml to local settings directory where mvn -X reads config files. But I still get this error:

`Beginning interaction for module default...
Sep 08, 2014 3:31:11 PM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=tactile-visitor-696&version=1-war&
403 Forbidden
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=en><meta charset=utf-8><meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width"><title>Error 403 (Forbidden)!!1</title><style>*{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2.png) no-repeat}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-r
atio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:55px;width:150px}</style><a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a><p><b>403.</b> <ins>ThatΓÇÖs an error.</ins><p>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=tactile-visitor-696&amp;version=1-war&amp;</code> from this server.  (Client IP address: 5.222.64.189)<br><br>We're sorry, but this service is not available in your country.<ins>ThatΓÇÖs all we know.</ins>`

Which means Maven is trying to post to https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=tactile-visitor-696&version=1-war& whithout using the proxy.

I read other similar problems like:

[Maven ignores settings.xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041782/maven-ignores-settings-xml-file)

[Maven proxy settings not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033286/maven-proxy-settings-not-working)

[How to set maven proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989097/how-to-set-maven-proxy)

but they were not much help.

How should I config Maven to solve this problem?

Comment: Might be helpful to look at the output of `help:effective-settings` to find out exactly what settings maven in using for proxies - see mojo doc [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-settings-mojo.html).